Unable to fetch data from smart contract into my frontend
I'm working on a lottery dapp using Solidity and Next.js. While trying to call the getEnteranceFeefunction from my contract, I keep encountering the following error:
ContractFunctionExecutionError: The contract function "getEnteranceFee" returned no data ("0x").

This is happening even though my contract is successfully deployed, and the address appears correct. I even exclusively provided the abi of the function. The function doesn't seem to return any data, and I'm not sure why.
Here's what I've done:

Deployed the contract on a local Hardhat network.
The contractdeployment output shows the correct contract address.
I'm using useReadContract from wagmi to call the function.
The function is defined as pure in my Solidity contract.

Here’s a breakdown of the relevant code:
Solidity Contract:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;


import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/dev/VRFConsumerBaseV2Plus.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/dev/interfaces/IVRFCoordinatorV2Plus.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/automation/interfaces/AutomationCompatibleInterface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/dev/libraries/VRFV2PlusClient.sol";

error Lottery__NotEnoughETHEntered();
error Lottery_TransferFailed();
error Lottery_NotOpen();
error Lottery_UpKeepNotNeeded(uint256 currentBalance, uint256 numPlayers, uint256 lotteryState);


contract Lottery is VRFConsumerBaseV2Plus, AutomationCompatibleInterface {
    /* Type declaration*/
    enum LotteryState {
        OPEN,
        CALCULATING
    } //uint256 0=OPEN, 1=CALCULATING

    /* State Variables */
    uint256 private immutable i_enteranceFee;
    address payable[] private s_players;
    // IVRFCoordinatorV2Plus private immutable i_vrfCoordinator;
    bytes32 private immutable i_gasLane;
    uint256 private immutable i_subscriptionId;
    uint32 private immutable i_callbackGasLimit;
    uint16 private constant REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS = 3;
    uint32 private constant NUM_WORDS = 1;

    //Lottery Variables
    address private s_recentWinner;
    LotteryState private s_lotteryState;
    uint256 private s_lastTimeStamp;
    uint256 private immutable i_interval;

    /* Evnets*/
    event LotteryEnter(address indexed player);
    event RequestedLotteryWinner(uint256 indexed requestId);
    event WinnerPicked(address indexed winner);

    /* Functions */
    constructor(
        address vrfCoordinatorV2, //contract address
        uint256 enteranceFee,
        bytes32 gasLane,
        uint256 subscriptionId,
        uint32 callbackGasLimit,
        uint256 interval
    ) VRFConsumerBaseV2Plus(vrfCoordinatorV2) {
        i_enteranceFee = enteranceFee;
        // i_vrfCoordinator = IVRFCoordinatorV2Plus(vrfCoordinatorV2);
        i_gasLane = gasLane;
        i_subscriptionId = subscriptionId;
        i_callbackGasLimit = callbackGasLimit;
        s_lotteryState = LotteryState.OPEN;
        s_lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp; //block.timestamp is a globally known variable
        i_interval = interval;
    }

    function enterLottery() public payable {
        if (msg.value < i_enteranceFee) {
            revert Lottery__NotEnoughETHEntered();
        }
        if (s_lotteryState != LotteryState.OPEN) {
            revert Lottery_NotOpen();
        }
        s_players.push(payable(msg.sender));

        emit LotteryEnter(msg.sender);
    }


    function checkUpkeep(bytes memory /*checkData*/ )
        public
        view
        override
        returns (bool upKeepNeeded, bytes memory /* performData*/ )
    {
        bool isOpen = (LotteryState.OPEN == s_lotteryState);
        bool timePassed = (block.timestamp - s_lastTimeStamp) > i_interval;
        bool hasPlayers = (s_players.length > 0);
        bool hasBalance = address(this).balance > 0;
        upKeepNeeded = (isOpen && timePassed && hasPlayers && hasBalance);

        return (upKeepNeeded, "");
    }

    function performUpkeep(bytes calldata /*performData*/ ) external override {
        (bool upKeepNeeded,) = checkUpkeep("");
        if (!upKeepNeeded) {
            revert Lottery_UpKeepNotNeeded(address(this).balance, s_players.length, uint256(s_lotteryState));
        }

        s_lotteryState = LotteryState.CALCULATING;

        uint256 requestId = s_vrfCoordinator.requestRandomWords(
            VRFV2PlusClient.RandomWordsRequest({
                keyHash: i_gasLane, //gasLane
                subId: i_subscriptionId, //Subscription ID that we need for funding requests (here it is to request a random number)
                requestConfirmations: REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS, //It says how many confirmations the chainlink node should wait before responding
                callbackGasLimit: i_callbackGasLimit, //The limit for how much gas to use for the callback request to our contract's fulfillRandomWords() function.
                numWords: NUM_WORDS, // number of random words we need
                extraArgs: VRFV2PlusClient._argsToBytes(VRFV2PlusClient.ExtraArgsV1({nativePayment: false}))
            })
        );

        //THis is redudant!!
        emit RequestedLotteryWinner(requestId);
    }

    function fulfillRandomWords(uint256, /*requestId*/ uint256[] calldata randomWords) internal override {
        uint256 indexOfWinner = randomWords[0] % s_players.length;
        address payable recentWinner = s_players[indexOfWinner];
        s_recentWinner = recentWinner;
        s_lotteryState = LotteryState.OPEN;
        s_players = new address payable[](0);
        s_lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
        (bool success,) = recentWinner.call{value: address(this).balance}("");

        if (!success) {
            revert Lottery_TransferFailed();
        }
        emit WinnerPicked(recentWinner);
    }

    /* view / pure functions*/

    function getEnteranceFee() public view returns (uint256) {
        return i_enteranceFee;
    }

    function getPalyers(uint256 index) public view returns (address) {
        return s_players[index];
    }

    function getRecentWinner() public view returns (address) {
        return s_recentWinner;
    }

    function getLotteryState() public view returns (LotteryState) {
        return s_lotteryState;
    }

    function getNumWords() public pure returns (uint256) {
        return NUM_WORDS;
    }

    function getNumberOfPlayers() public view returns (uint256) {
        return s_players.length;
    }

    function getLatestTimeStamp() public view returns (uint256) {
        return s_lastTimeStamp;
    }

    function getRequestConfirmations() public pure returns (uint256) {
        return REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS;
    }

    function getInterval() public view returns (uint256) {
        return i_interval;
    }
}


React Component:
import React from "react"
import { abi, contractAddresses } from "../constants"
import { useAccount, useReadContract } from "wagmi"
import { config } from "../config"
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"

const LotteryEntrance = () => {
    const [enteranceFee, setEnteranceFee] = useState(null)
    const [contractAddress, setContractAddress] = useState(null)

    const { isConnected, address } = useAccount()
    const account = useAccount()
    const chainId = account.chainId
    console.log("chainId:", chainId)
    // console.log(contractAddress[chainId][0])

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchContractAddress = async () => {
            if (chainId && contractAddresses[chainId]) {
                const address = contractAddresses[chainId][0]
                setContractAddress(address)
                console.log("Contract Address:", address)
            } else {
                console.error("Invalid chain ID or contract address not found for this chain")
            }
        }

        if (chainId) {
            fetchContractAddress()
        }
    }, [chainId])

    const {
        data: fee,
        isLoading,
        error,
    } = useReadContract({
        abi: [
            {
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "getEnteranceFee",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "uint256",
          "name": "",
          "type": "uint256"
        }
      ],
      "stateMutability": "view",
      "type": "function"
    },
        ],
        address: "0xCf7Ed3AccA5a467e9e704C703E8D87F634fB0Fc9",
        functionName: "getEnteranceFee",
        args: [],
        enabled: !!contractAddress,
    })
    console.log("fee:", fee)

    useEffect(() => {
        async function updateUI() {
            console.log("1")
            if (isConnected && fee) {
                console.log("2")
                const enteranceFee = await fee.toString()
                setEnteranceFee(enteranceFee)
                console.log("enteranceFee:", enteranceFee)
            }
        }
        updateUI()
    }, [isConnected, fee])
    if (isLoading) return <div>Loading entrance fee...</div>
    if (error) {
        console.log(error)
        return <div>Error fetching entrance fee: {error.message}</div>
    }

    return <div>Lottery entrance fee: {enteranceFee ? `${enteranceFee}` : "N/A"}</div>
}

export default LotteryEntrance


Hardhat deployment output:
Nothing to compile
Local network detected! Deploying mocks...
deploying "VRFCoordinatorV2_5Mock" (tx: 0x5610f99e25943d1e61152d198e3bc82947059e723c727708f35121f44c6722f6)...: deployed at 0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3 with 3057197 gas
Mocks Deployed!
----------------------------------------------------
local network detected
.....
subscriptionId :  105366054316822285762677720084519815636149581806396942115848005774721615015833
enterance fee: BigNumber { value: "5000000000000000" }
deploying "Lottery" (tx: 0x3d42183eb5cbf3c183e843614df291642e287639272f171430967a49137c1696)...: deployed at 0xCf7Ed3AccA5a467e9e704C703E8D87F634fB0Fc9 with 1005908 gas
Consumer is added
-------------------------------------------

Error:
The contract function "getEnteranceFee" returned no data ("0x").

I've verified that the contract address is correct and that the contract does contain the getRequestConfirmations function. However, the function still returns no data.
For further details, you can check out my GitHub repository: https://github.com/Alisha-Reddy/Lottery_dApp
Any suggestions on what might be causing this issue? I'd appreciate any help!

It's showing Lottery entrance fee: 0.005 ETH on my end though. Make sure that you've selected Ethereum Sepolia network in your MetaMask, because your contract is deployed on Ethereum Sepolia.

Yes, I guess I did select Sepolia network in MetaMask and still got the same error. Instead of wagmi useReadContract function, I used ethers.js to fetch the data and it's working now. But I'll once again try and follow your suggestion. Thank you

I figured out what the issue was. The useReadContract() function in Wagmi works perfectly fine on Ethereum mainnet and testnets like Sepolia. However, it doesn't seem to work as expected on the Hardhat localhost network.
This is why I wasn't able to fetch the getEntranceFee data while connected to the localhost. If you're encountering the same issue, try  switching to a testnet environment for local development.
